# Hiding users id when paginating with php

Tags: php, html

I have an old project that I realized has a security flaw. When paginating I assigned the users id to a hidden input value. You can see it when looking at the source. Does any one have a quick solution? I can only think of using an associative array that would put the assigned value as the hidden value and keep it from view or searching using their emails, but I would like to keep those hidden as well.

```
 echo '
       <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card h-100">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="/uploads/'.$userPic['Link1'].'" height="400" width="400" alt="anotherOne"/>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title ">'.$row['first'].' '.$row['last'].'<span style="float:right;">'.$row['r'].'</span></h5>
        <p class="card-text">'.$row['briefDesc'].'</p>
       <form action="setting.php" method="GET">   
                   <input type="hidden" name="time" value='.$tSelected.'>
                   <input type="hidden" name="date" value='.$dSelected.'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="idNumber" value='.$P_id.'>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="buttonSearch">See Profile</button>
                    </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>';
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: @TimMorton I think I didn't write it out well enough. This is being printed out after querying for users that match certain criteria. The $P_id is from a select all query. This is not related to a session variable.

Comment: What is the security flaw in allowing users to see their own ID? Or, is the flaw that someone, through JS, could change the ID and enumerate other user’s data?

Comment: @ChrisHaas It's actually another user being able to see it unfortunately. The code above is a card display which is looped over and filled in with other users information. So it exposes all the other users id's. I think the easiest solution is to query by name and email instead of id.

Comment: Hi @Dr5056732, it still comes back to what the security problem actually is? My User ID at SO is `231316`, but what can you do with the information? User ID enumeration is usually pretty easy to figure out, so if you have a security issue related to that, it is probably bigger than you might think actually.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas you just saved me a headache. I just read somewhere that you should never expose the ID. Looks like everything else is setup so no User enumeration can occur.

Comment: Just to be clear, user enumeration is usually where someone sees that their own ID is 27 and then can guess or infer that there's probably a 28 and a 29 and so on. So on this site, I can enumerate user IDs by incrementing my own by 1 in the profile page. The security issue is that if someone does enumerate them, can they can access to something. I would hit the URLs in your app that support User IDs, both as a logged in and logged out user, and see if you can "jump" or gain access to anything. Usually, the session data holds the User ID, not the URLs (or post data), but there are times.

Comment: Your comments are much appreciated @ChrisHaas. Non of my urls show user id's at any point and are session data only. So i think i'm Ok. From what I read about Id enumerate was exposure at login and password reset, but it looks like i took the cautionary steps against that. Would you happen to have an article or resource that dives into this topic? Thank you again!

Comment: @ChrisHaas To add on to my comment above. A user could enter in a random number to that value and then submit, but they would see potentially another profile. At that point there is nothing else they can do it would just be seeing profile of others with no access to anything so I think I'm all good.

Comment: @Dr5056732, I don't have a specific resource on this, just 20+ years of experience. For password resets, I think the (current) general recommendation is to set a nonce on the user account in the database, something long and random, and send that in the query string or email. When the user clicks the link, validate the nonce first and then delete/expire it from the database. If the user clients the link again (or someone tries guessing), you just prompt with a message saying "The link is no longer valid, please request a new one" or similar.

Comment: @ChrisHaas that's what I got right now with a 20min hook that expires or is replaced if re-requested. I really cant thank you enough. You saved me a massive pain. Your website is awesome and a treasure trove of info and will be frequenting it often! People like you make this site great. I was excepting a bunch of snarky replies, but you came in and saved the day. Cheers!